# Create a matrix to show overlaps among multiple GRanges

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am trying to find a way to efficiently extract a matrix showing '0' or '1' when comparing different `GRange` objects. In my example:

```
df <- data.frame(chr = c("chr1", "chr10"), start = c(1,4), end=c(2, 4))
gr.1 <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df)

df <- data.frame(chr = c("chr1", "chr10"), start = c(2,3), end=c(2, 4))
gr.2 <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df)

df <- data.frame(chr = c("chr1"), start = c(1), end=c(1))
gr.3 <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df)
```

I tried `findOverlaps` to evaluate the overlaps among these regions but apparently it can't deal with more than two `GRanges`:

```
> GenomicRanges::findOverlaps(gr.1, gr.2, gr.3)
> Error in IRanges:::NCList_find_overlaps_in_groups(ranges(query),
> q_space,  :    'maxgap' must be a single integer
```

Moreover, my required output would be something like this example data-frame:

```
out <- "gr.1 gr.2 gr.3
chr1-1 1  0  1
chr1-2 1  1  0
chr10-3 0 1  0
chr10-4 1 1  0"

out <- read.table(text=out, header=TRUE)
```

Any idea to wisely export it?

Comment: Can you provide more minimal sample data (is it really necessary to have 3 `GRanges` containing 1000 features each)? Furthermore, `regionR::createRandomRegions` has further dependencies that makes it unnecessarily awkward to generate the sample data. It would help a lot if you were to provide smaller sample data including matching expected output. To address your problem, this is essentially a multi-dataset merge, the solution of which is usually quite straight-forward by using e.g. `Reduce(findOverlaps, list_of_gr)` and processing the resulting object.

Comment: In fact `regionR::createRandomRegions` was the simplest way I have found to represent a random set of genomic ranges. This is quite new function and fits my example. Moreover, I am not sure that is that straight forward to generate random genomic regions (see https://www.biostars.org/p/225520/). Finally, I am simulating 1000 genomic regions to increase the change to have some complex overlap patterns as my real data-set. Also, `Reduce(findOverlaps, glg)` just gives me an error.

Comment: I strongly recommend generating a minimal set of `GRanges` by hand; I can almost guarantee that you will get very little (positive) response with unwieldy sample data like the one you're giving. If you generate data by hand, you can also make sure that ranges overlap; no need to generate that many ranges! As I explained, it's very difficult (impossible) to provide proper and specific help without having access to minimal sample data; using `Reduce` is definitely an option, but to make it work we need data.

Comment: [updated] Keep in mind that you're asking other people here to spend their free time to help you with *your* problem. Number one rule is: Make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: I see your point and meant no offense to people that dedicate time to help others at stackoverflow. Hope that my update is more digestible now.

Comment: No offence taken;-) This is a surprisingly involved problem (and I remember resorting to `bedtools intersect` in the past for similar tasks). Please see below for a (partial) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, here is a partial solution that shows only the overlapping regions between the first and any additional `GRanges` (this should generate results similar to those from [`bedtools intersect`](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html) which allows one to "*identify overlaps between a single query (-a) file and multiple database files (-b) at once*"); this should be a good starting point for further refinement.

We can define a function that takes any number of `GRanges` and identifies overlapping ranges between the first `GRanges` and any additional `GRanges` using `findOverlaps`; the intersecting regions are then obtained from `pintersect`.

Please note that I make use of the common `tidyverse` syntax; while this is not strictly necessary (for every `purrr::map`/`purrr::map2` function one can use their base R `lapply`/`mapply` equivalents), I prefer the `tidyverse` approach for code readability.

```
multiOverlap <- function(...) {
    require(GenomicRanges)
    require(tidyverse)

    # Store GRanges in list
    lst <- list(...)
    names(lst) <- paste0("gr", 1:length(lst))

    # Calculate mutual overlaps
    lst.matches <- map(lst[-1L], ~ findOverlaps(lst[[1L]], .x))

    # List of intersecting regions
    lst.gr <- map2(
        lst[-1L], lst.matches,
        ~pintersect(lst[[1]][queryHits(.y)], .x[subjectHits(.y)]))
    names(lst.gr) <- paste0("gr1-gr", 2:length(lst))

    # Convert GRanges to data.frame and reshape data
    map(lst.gr, ~.x %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        unite(locus, seqnames, start, sep = "-") %>%
        select(locus)) %>%
        bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
        separate(id, into = c("grx", "gry")) %>%
        gather(gr, no, -locus) %>%
        transmute(
            locus,
            no,
            val = 1) %>%
            spread(no, val, fill = 0)
}
```

When we apply this function to the three sample `GRanges` we get the following result

```
multiOverlap(gr.1, gr.2, gr.3)
#    locus gr1 gr2 gr3
#1  chr1-1   1   0   1
#2  chr1-2   1   1   0
#3 chr10-4   1   1   0
```

---

### Update

Another (fast) option might be to use `data.table`; especially when working with genomic data `data.table`s pass-by-reference properties, avoiding deep copies, makes it very attractive (and fast).

Here is a solution that exactly reproduces your expected output

```
# Load the library
library(data.table)

# Convert GRanges to data.table and row-bind entries
dt <- rbindlist(
    lapply(list(gr.1 = gr.1, gr.2 = gr.2, gr.3 = gr.3), as.data.table),
    idcol = "id")

# Remove width and strand
dt[, c("width", "strand") := NULL]

# Expand rows by range using start and end
dt <- dt[, .(pos = seq(start, end, by = 1L)), by = .(id, seqnames, grp = 1:nrow(dt))]

# Remove helper group label
dt[, grp := NULL]

# Unite seqnames and pos into one column
dt <- dt[, .(locus = do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = "-")), id, pos), .SDcols = seqnames:pos]

# Add count variable
dt[, ct := 1]

# Convert from long to wide
dcast(dt, locus ~ id, value.var = "ct", fill = 0)
#     locus gr.1 gr.2 gr.3
#1:  chr1-1    1    0    1
#2:  chr1-2    1    1    0
#3: chr10-3    0    1    0
#4: chr10-4    1    1    0
```

And we're done:-) It's easy to wrap above lines in a convenience function if necessary.